# Castle-Windsor wire private field

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I am trying to figure out how to make Windsor autowire private instance fields. Is there any way to do this?

I know perfectly well how do it with properties and constructors, but that does not really suit me for this project.

What I want is to do something like this:

```
[Autowired]
private IProvider _provider;
```

That is, introduce a custom attribute that I can put on the fields that I want to autowire.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need that if you've constructor injection? It's just about passing them in the constructor and set that private field.

Comment: Try creating your own facility. register on the OnComponentCreated event. There you have the object. You can manually set the private properties. (I don't recommend this though)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer if you really want to know, it's because the project I am working on has strict guidelines that all classes must be a POCO, but with dependencies that must not be publicly visible. Furthermore, I just like that way of thought. It works very well in the Java world.



Marwijn Thank you, I'll look into that. Though I think I settled for a more manual solution for now. But it'll be a good place to look if I get into it again.

Comment: @Stmated BTW I don't see how an overloaded constructor with one or more parameter might defeat the point of POCOs :O

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Well, I actually don't know about .NET in difference to Java, but as far as I know one of the main rules of a POCO is that it contains a parameterless constructor. 

Besides, I asked a specific question, and knew about the other ways. Thanks for the pointers anyway :)

Comment: @Stmated In my opinion, design patterns aren't meant to be followed *as is* in any situation and any project. Open your mind!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I did open my mind, and someone told me to use constructor injection instead; so look where that got me.

Comment: @Stmated I find both *closed-mind* looking for an unexisting feature and not looking for an existing feature!!